# Create Table from a specific column that contains XML data

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I am in a situation where a specific set of data that is critical to a project is stored in a SQL Server table, but the column contents are in XML.

The table is in the below format

| ID | DS_RowGuid | PCScreenStructureVariantID | Xml | ToScreen | FromScreen | LRScreen | _FlgTCF | DS_RowVersion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2058 | 8771805B-42FC-4D43-8F37-949AFB89F372 | 185 | XML STUFF | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0x000000003F27E191 |

The XML column when queried returns this XML:

```
<IGPosEvtHallStruct Ver="1">
  <Rows>
    <Row Coord="0" Id="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" Legend="J" />
    <Row Coord="1" Id="96b8b07e-43cb-4812-9b3f-ce1b95e38cb2" Legend="I" />
    ---
  </Rows>
  <Columns>
    <Column Coord="0" Id="96af2fb1-3816-410c-b99d-5d9270c13b58" />
    <Column Coord="1" Id="a518716a-fabc-433c-9945-21056b7d1b96" />
    <Column Coord="2" Id="bc7fc15e-0c15-4aa1-b323-a3c6d236c904" />
    ---
  </Columns>
  <Places>
    <Place Id="296178b2-707e-4f4a-b82f-57863d23d984" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="96af2fb1-3816-410c-b99d-5d9270c13b58" Symbol="" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="f79f5249-711b-4d85-a1ad-f5308d431801" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="a518716a-fabc-433c-9945-21056b7d1b96" Symbol="" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="7b116ee5-8f1f-42b8-9eaa-2be6b29ce8d6" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="bc7fc15e-0c15-4aa1-b323-a3c6d236c904" Symbol="15" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="c90c7156-9b5f-44eb-8e59-672b4f47c248" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="faa1bb37-22bc-4b35-8d83-34bef01ce04a" Symbol="14" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="0f5995ce-47ac-453d-b37c-a04d1dcbd211" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="918c650b-9402-4aff-a03b-3770c60e626e" Symbol="13" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="ac1200b6-ee15-4c16-9c33-4413c9577b6c" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="a2d816dc-d777-4a30-8b47-e80d89ee2b7f" Symbol="12" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="56905ff8-369d-4f6e-8e77-0f5e2f780796" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="199da003-1cc5-4e6f-9c37-cbae76f6f48a" Symbol="11" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="e6fb8ad4-b1be-4017-a753-4cac31adf423" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="3f74a90e-b2bb-48a6-9a68-5e9b65a8a1c3" Symbol="10" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="fb03dc89-12a0-49cd-b978-a7e4bc355bdb" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="234c9999-788c-415f-88fc-b77f79e493a8" Symbol="9" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="35700ff7-6405-4ca8-9e74-a44da2e0d1c0" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="91b2e41d-9de7-49a8-b37e-5036a2c64d39" Symbol="8" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="f3be70c9-93a7-4824-b4b0-3d8d6bc317a5" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="2bb7dc3b-1355-4343-9e20-dced0778db3a" Symbol="7" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="be980a4e-49ac-4b29-8e25-92937545e088" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="027b3efa-81f9-456b-b13a-742bbbfed357" Symbol="6" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="612734a4-ead9-4fd2-9d14-d0a557464bec" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="c37c3c6e-ca2d-4b8a-9b67-53d8605b9ad0" Symbol="5" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="f753c89a-6e9a-4dbb-bf37-2110ab941293" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="28e1b0b4-7e92-4814-b972-42cb5e04f39e" Symbol="4" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="5d318aab-2775-4dd3-81b4-2f78f5d3bcbd" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="5eb3a4dc-3a1a-4f5f-8991-997533ff9912" Symbol="3" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="2b6c033d-9be7-41c3-ad14-60a59ef490b0" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="65a88ecf-6e0e-4a7c-b81e-6d2e15498011" Symbol="2" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="3aea20d0-ec44-48b4-8456-0d923499c299" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="3ddc9559-faa6-45da-97f0-c43db4e3c827" Symbol="1" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="b6ab027f-5e85-479e-86b7-17e2abfee59a" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="6734cca8-5391-4255-a45a-8713be965c4f" Symbol="" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="cd61be80-4c41-4f90-998c-42b68587fce5" RowId="2768c6d4-fe88-441e-ae8a-4af0060af1bc" ColId="79e43ba6-5488-471e-b46d-ba59c97b4f8c" Symbol="" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="57b924dc-4c2e-4f16-bab5-9b47f9434d28" RowId="96b8b07e-43cb-4812-9b3f-ce1b95e38cb2" ColId="96af2fb1-3816-410c-b99d-5d9270c13b58" Symbol="" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="537ed01e-2743-4183-aa60-0d722d42edfe" RowId="96b8b07e-43cb-4812-9b3f-ce1b95e38cb2" ColId="a518716a-fabc-433c-9945-21056b7d1b96" Symbol="" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="a57db94e-8bb7-4818-af19-9a7acbcf5e37" RowId="96b8b07e-43cb-4812-9b3f-ce1b95e38cb2" ColId="bc7fc15e-0c15-4aa1-b323-a3c6d236c904" Symbol="15" Kind="Excluded" />
    <Place Id="85b49eb4-2674-4b39-98c3-fc99c74293a0" RowId="96b8b07e-43cb-4812-9b3f-ce1b95e38cb2" ColId="faa1bb37-22bc-4b35-8d83-34bef01ce04a" Symbol="14" Kind="Included" />
    <Place Id="1fbb02b0-3cc9-48ea-8f29-63c558424bb9" RowId="96b8b07e-43cb-4812-9b3f-ce1b95e38cb2" ColId="918c650b-9402-4aff-a03b-3770c60e626e" Symbol="13" Kind="Included" />
   ---
  </Places>
  <CoachGroups />

  <CustomGroups>
    <Group Id="4819c2e6-c8fc-455a-98a1-b9d0021703e2" GroupSeatsId="55feabb6-bd57-436c-b4f9-5f5f7ef9b485">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="01c930c9-0d5a-48f4-b5d0-1416c8a8c99f" />
        <Place Id="3609a78d-2d8c-4c96-8b06-2648226cbcab" />
        <Place Id="a10ec0ec-9b5a-4279-a40f-2103104ff979" />
        <Place Id="e7580756-cc38-41a4-b4d1-d356136fe9d5" />
        <Place Id="c189a0db-f53e-4a99-a5cd-7318c4506f2d" />
        <Place Id="67717bd9-e9d2-414f-ae6d-de4c2bd7b53a" />
        <Place Id="39fbca3d-acd6-4248-99d4-d5503151affb" />
        <Place Id="795f2264-5564-4cb4-8c78-c7382b7a2789" />
        <Place Id="c8a8bf32-0626-4a02-ab93-34fd17739787" />
        <Place Id="20e06b4d-333a-42cc-ba16-72eaa92e0eff" />
        <Place Id="9a1d1746-acd1-4cd5-ab86-d24ba1483d8c" />
        <Place Id="b840f33c-2b21-4c89-9eb1-a0bb637e0ab8" />
        <Place Id="66ea913c-1f8f-45d3-b1bb-f6936df9f9db" />
        <Place Id="77540b03-8284-4a2a-ab79-33526ab928fc" />
        <Place Id="a4047c47-59da-43ba-adc3-c0d0a8b0bb14" />
        <Place Id="b9094a20-ce0a-46e6-9db4-f2e9294034cb" />
        <Place Id="c8e6f136-ef51-4853-97e9-ea27458af4cd" />
        <Place Id="6bc7b667-b3a6-4cbb-952f-8cc452476416" />
        <Place Id="ef6edd3f-9da6-4c97-bf17-ea22f6d6f9f6" />
        <Place Id="58b683e4-cacc-4ae8-bff6-bd3816bdc507" />
        <Place Id="0ff27d45-4f6d-47a4-94f7-f7e45ded5d34" />
        <Place Id="9cf8df8e-f79e-4090-b2d6-dc937a474adf" />
        <Place Id="3e5d92f4-db67-4ff3-9d6b-9b8a44fb94c4" />
        <Place Id="9a7659b4-2137-4797-badf-2a40ba09dd3a" />
        <Place Id="e9c7e3fb-67f3-404a-a54f-ebf2d16d8b84" />
        <Place Id="7baca53e-f48b-485f-9d53-ad1a93199194" />
        <Place Id="23c72a9f-e4f9-42bb-a64f-c11af162a8e8" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
    <Group Id="b49c7f1a-1fc2-455e-8d00-41cea3dac82d" GroupSeatsId="55feabb6-bd57-436c-b4f9-5f5f7ef9b485">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="7b116ee5-8f1f-42b8-9eaa-2be6b29ce8d6" />
        <Place Id="c90c7156-9b5f-44eb-8e59-672b4f47c248" />
        <Place Id="ac1200b6-ee15-4c16-9c33-4413c9577b6c" />
        <Place Id="56905ff8-369d-4f6e-8e77-0f5e2f780796" />
        <Place Id="fb03dc89-12a0-49cd-b978-a7e4bc355bdb" />
        <Place Id="35700ff7-6405-4ca8-9e74-a44da2e0d1c0" />
        <Place Id="be980a4e-49ac-4b29-8e25-92937545e088" />
        <Place Id="612734a4-ead9-4fd2-9d14-d0a557464bec" />
        <Place Id="5d318aab-2775-4dd3-81b4-2f78f5d3bcbd" />
        <Place Id="2b6c033d-9be7-41c3-ad14-60a59ef490b0" />
        <Place Id="85b49eb4-2674-4b39-98c3-fc99c74293a0" />
        <Place Id="1fbb02b0-3cc9-48ea-8f29-63c558424bb9" />
        <Place Id="fc41d588-e495-4c4d-91cd-88949f367264" />
        <Place Id="4d401101-207b-4a37-a9fe-957d147712b4" />
        <Place Id="f06b4ceb-7872-4f1c-87f9-5a1bfb428958" />
        <Place Id="a71189db-2198-4c34-b57f-8de5a5938cbf" />
        <Place Id="d675a530-5e9e-4cf4-990a-566386e5fb8a" />
        <Place Id="496b00bf-2e21-4f34-a11a-06235769e84c" />
        <Place Id="15dafb9c-f90a-476f-a6ad-cde5db74407c" />
        <Place Id="a21c3a36-5c6d-42e6-99e6-b1992ec7a37e" />
        <Place Id="5bb4e85f-99f8-4ab2-82e8-d6ae10a316bd" />
        <Place Id="24dc5ffa-c785-4b73-8bc0-1bd43ae591d0" />
        <Place Id="4c323c73-7e2f-401b-a3da-3451a92487fc" />
        <Place Id="8cc1370e-6824-4a34-9d3a-040a155ae229" />
        <Place Id="b2c088c1-e132-432d-b920-907c6c813bc4" />
        <Place Id="93e046f3-03de-4d7a-9654-9ea2d3ba19d5" />
        <Place Id="01ce83f1-3380-42df-9ee0-c300ab432b2b" />
        <Place Id="ca8e2273-8c07-4b99-8c9b-2ccbb709e839" />
        <Place Id="372c67b7-59aa-42a4-9638-ff4e5282d0eb" />
        <Place Id="27f9e128-86df-4280-87e8-9355c1061ce4" />
        <Place Id="27e4b385-965d-4c17-8e38-8cbbdd136a3f" />
        <Place Id="b2610871-3fb1-48e5-917e-d7148358861f" />
        <Place Id="b6a61399-2fca-4a36-95ce-04faaf1de30c" />
        <Place Id="e1f7d937-65dd-4e63-9cfa-a032d8c0e19f" />
        <Place Id="8e5cc633-f5c5-4067-9f8d-76bd0cd28385" />
        <Place Id="ce74b491-f868-403b-b5e5-4366426e8a8c" />
        <Place Id="6d9c175d-97f9-4132-9209-c55f2152aeb0" />
        <Place Id="b5c7b2fc-c4ad-4e9d-bc6e-8cb07afe9273" />
        <Place Id="c20cd9ca-70bd-4851-8675-f02a48ea1271" />
        <Place Id="df9f060e-fc32-4bd7-b3f7-52898779008c" />
        <Place Id="655bb2b5-a7a0-4794-bfca-9feb355ba97b" />
        <Place Id="ef8eb9b0-9129-41a8-adb2-a28208a729ee" />
        <Place Id="4faa4dbb-5066-42a7-a5fa-ea2295d12ca4" />
        <Place Id="36adea82-928a-4c0d-9fb0-d147e09ca181" />
        <Place Id="8ddc5442-16fe-4af5-9548-efdc4f6d7dd8" />
        <Place Id="cd7db0bf-cc5a-498f-bdf1-75adcaa0e0ce" />
        <Place Id="465e5048-e063-43ab-8375-dc0a2a930054" />
        <Place Id="97905665-0f1a-42c2-bf0a-76c4156ea678" />
        <Place Id="4364e8b7-1113-4ba8-b103-91ce542c03e2" />
        <Place Id="545f2336-dad9-4378-9948-d138394a657c" />
        <Place Id="4307cc49-4cea-4089-8f5f-7992eb9d10f7" />
        <Place Id="29dc4b9a-3239-451e-baf8-7ded37fe0e03" />
        <Place Id="accf0603-0070-4f4e-8e16-31029ba270ff" />
        <Place Id="d3526c22-0816-457b-bd0a-a830850f3b99" />
        <Place Id="b3540ee8-8b16-42f9-bf99-8a5c1c549cfd" />
        <Place Id="b3fc6e24-ac14-4687-a298-83de9cb3752d" />
        <Place Id="cf27f59c-e85f-44ae-83c6-91b189b94446" />
        <Place Id="fb917c61-4659-47ae-89e6-e40f270f7ddc" />
        <Place Id="f4646afa-b941-4971-a4c3-39538b5fe53a" />
        <Place Id="0331765a-05aa-435e-ae57-46a7d910c79f" />
        <Place Id="a9f3957e-c9e3-4a9e-9c96-64255d449c4a" />
        <Place Id="ce19ce74-e5a2-4a91-96aa-eb1ab37d094b" />
        <Place Id="d1c31454-291a-418e-8d9b-f95b1e60658b" />
        <Place Id="3f3f222e-2488-46d8-95fe-2b735303a6dc" />
        <Place Id="38e9dc06-52cc-415b-b00f-de344ab28f3d" />
        <Place Id="157e49e4-c2e5-4dcb-bc97-5b311481007e" />
        <Place Id="8979cc1d-93bc-4529-a1d5-41709b54fc89" />
        <Place Id="c7fad1db-261b-46e0-99b3-bcd95b9e7860" />
        <Place Id="95eadfb4-2738-4ce1-b0c7-df76a9dfbf34" />
        <Place Id="426e875c-68fe-41a2-975b-5792ca8b59b6" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
  </CustomGroups>
  <Wheelchairs>
    <Wheelchair Id="03df3286-5ffb-4239-b4af-3ec2ff643df8" PlaceId="a10ec0ec-9b5a-4279-a40f-2103104ff979" />
  </Wheelchairs>
  <LoungeGroups />
  <SalesChannelGroups>
    <Group Id="e00d7780-285b-46d1-ba82-bd1393077b66" BlockedSalesChannelID="0b884544-5660-4c31-9c59-d57e41733b8e">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="e7580756-cc38-41a4-b4d1-d356136fe9d5" />
        <Place Id="c189a0db-f53e-4a99-a5cd-7318c4506f2d" />
        <Place Id="c6828de4-1696-44ac-b2e4-bdce7cb25fd7" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
    <Group Id="78c91c03-b754-403c-8f43-b78deb92afd4" BlockedSalesChannelID="5cb99449-ca4d-4a83-b3bb-2e57c8c2f98d">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="e7580756-cc38-41a4-b4d1-d356136fe9d5" />
        <Place Id="c189a0db-f53e-4a99-a5cd-7318c4506f2d" />
        <Place Id="c6828de4-1696-44ac-b2e4-bdce7cb25fd7" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
    <Group Id="702b51c3-50c0-4077-9a29-da8091ea0c67" BlockedSalesChannelID="1a1fe703-587a-4885-8fd3-496b7321d4b9">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="e7580756-cc38-41a4-b4d1-d356136fe9d5" />
        <Place Id="c189a0db-f53e-4a99-a5cd-7318c4506f2d" />
        <Place Id="c6828de4-1696-44ac-b2e4-bdce7cb25fd7" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
    <Group Id="6275ae54-e3c7-412d-801d-c60a948fb2a0" BlockedSalesChannelID="fc483f27-ba50-4441-a609-65cadb6d6564">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="e7580756-cc38-41a4-b4d1-d356136fe9d5" />
        <Place Id="c189a0db-f53e-4a99-a5cd-7318c4506f2d" />
        <Place Id="c6828de4-1696-44ac-b2e4-bdce7cb25fd7" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
    <Group Id="31ad6d3b-a84e-49f9-af10-3c45d0f7a7b8" BlockedSalesChannelID="0b884544-5660-4c31-9c59-d57e41733b8e">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="2b6c033d-9be7-41c3-ad14-60a59ef490b0" />
        <Place Id="5d318aab-2775-4dd3-81b4-2f78f5d3bcbd" />
        <Place Id="612734a4-ead9-4fd2-9d14-d0a557464bec" />
        <Place Id="be980a4e-49ac-4b29-8e25-92937545e088" />
        <Place Id="35700ff7-6405-4ca8-9e74-a44da2e0d1c0" />
        <Place Id="fb03dc89-12a0-49cd-b978-a7e4bc355bdb" />
        <Place Id="56905ff8-369d-4f6e-8e77-0f5e2f780796" />
        <Place Id="ac1200b6-ee15-4c16-9c33-4413c9577b6c" />
        <Place Id="c90c7156-9b5f-44eb-8e59-672b4f47c248" />
        <Place Id="7b116ee5-8f1f-42b8-9eaa-2be6b29ce8d6" />
        <Place Id="a21c3a36-5c6d-42e6-99e6-b1992ec7a37e" />
        <Place Id="15dafb9c-f90a-476f-a6ad-cde5db74407c" />
        <Place Id="496b00bf-2e21-4f34-a11a-06235769e84c" />
        <Place Id="d675a530-5e9e-4cf4-990a-566386e5fb8a" />
        <Place Id="a71189db-2198-4c34-b57f-8de5a5938cbf" />
        <Place Id="f06b4ceb-7872-4f1c-87f9-5a1bfb428958" />
        <Place Id="4d401101-207b-4a37-a9fe-957d147712b4" />
        <Place Id="fc41d588-e495-4c4d-91cd-88949f367264" />
        <Place Id="1fbb02b0-3cc9-48ea-8f29-63c558424bb9" />
        <Place Id="85b49eb4-2674-4b39-98c3-fc99c74293a0" />
        <Place Id="5bb4e85f-99f8-4ab2-82e8-d6ae10a316bd" />
        <Place Id="24dc5ffa-c785-4b73-8bc0-1bd43ae591d0" />
        <Place Id="27f9e128-86df-4280-87e8-9355c1061ce4" />
        <Place Id="372c67b7-59aa-42a4-9638-ff4e5282d0eb" />
        <Place Id="ca8e2273-8c07-4b99-8c9b-2ccbb709e839" />
        <Place Id="01ce83f1-3380-42df-9ee0-c300ab432b2b" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
    <Group Id="7f420e48-32e2-43ec-9ff1-879fc8142665" BlockedSalesChannelID="5cb99449-ca4d-4a83-b3bb-2e57c8c2f98d">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="7b116ee5-8f1f-42b8-9eaa-2be6b29ce8d6" />
        <Place Id="c90c7156-9b5f-44eb-8e59-672b4f47c248" />
        <Place Id="0f5995ce-47ac-453d-b37c-a04d1dcbd211" />
        <Place Id="ac1200b6-ee15-4c16-9c33-4413c9577b6c" />
        <Place Id="56905ff8-369d-4f6e-8e77-0f5e2f780796" />
        <Place Id="e6fb8ad4-b1be-4017-a753-4cac31adf423" />
        <Place Id="fb03dc89-12a0-49cd-b978-a7e4bc355bdb" />
        <Place Id="35700ff7-6405-4ca8-9e74-a44da2e0d1c0" />
        <Place Id="f3be70c9-93a7-4824-b4b0-3d8d6bc317a5" />
        <Place Id="be980a4e-49ac-4b29-8e25-92937545e088" />
        <Place Id="612734a4-ead9-4fd2-9d14-d0a557464bec" />
        <Place Id="f753c89a-6e9a-4dbb-bf37-2110ab941293" />
        <Place Id="5d318aab-2775-4dd3-81b4-2f78f5d3bcbd" />
        <Place Id="2b6c033d-9be7-41c3-ad14-60a59ef490b0" />
        <Place Id="3aea20d0-ec44-48b4-8456-0d923499c299" />
        <Place Id="a57db94e-8bb7-4818-af19-9a7acbcf5e37" />
        <Place Id="85b49eb4-2674-4b39-98c3-fc99c74293a0" />
        <Place Id="1fbb02b0-3cc9-48ea-8f29-63c558424bb9" />
        <Place Id="9ed0fd93-9482-40a1-840a-9f3f880bbb0b" />
        <Place Id="fc41d588-e495-4c4d-91cd-88949f367264" />
        <Place Id="4d401101-207b-4a37-a9fe-957d147712b4" />
        <Place Id="fd961ab9-886e-47d6-9be6-8acb47a2765b" />
        <Place Id="f06b4ceb-7872-4f1c-87f9-5a1bfb428958" />
        <Place Id="a71189db-2198-4c34-b57f-8de5a5938cbf" />
        <Place Id="12d9bfe8-6929-49bf-a78d-d17cf7685c9b" />
        <Place Id="d675a530-5e9e-4cf4-990a-566386e5fb8a" />
        <Place Id="496b00bf-2e21-4f34-a11a-06235769e84c" />
        <Place Id="0bf88c52-6c56-481c-943e-1c174de79d25" />
        <Place Id="15dafb9c-f90a-476f-a6ad-cde5db74407c" />
        <Place Id="a21c3a36-5c6d-42e6-99e6-b1992ec7a37e" />
        <Place Id="5bb4e85f-99f8-4ab2-82e8-d6ae10a316bd" />
        <Place Id="24dc5ffa-c785-4b73-8bc0-1bd43ae591d0" />
        <Place Id="372c67b7-59aa-42a4-9638-ff4e5282d0eb" />
        <Place Id="27f9e128-86df-4280-87e8-9355c1061ce4" />
        <Place Id="3f409342-70a1-4d2d-b933-bf8726c9be21" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
    <Group Id="cec9e7d5-24af-40dc-89e4-2a3d220499f6" BlockedSalesChannelID="1a1fe703-587a-4885-8fd3-496b7321d4b9">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="7b116ee5-8f1f-42b8-9eaa-2be6b29ce8d6" />
        <Place Id="c90c7156-9b5f-44eb-8e59-672b4f47c248" />
        <Place Id="0f5995ce-47ac-453d-b37c-a04d1dcbd211" />
        <Place Id="ac1200b6-ee15-4c16-9c33-4413c9577b6c" />
        <Place Id="56905ff8-369d-4f6e-8e77-0f5e2f780796" />
        <Place Id="e6fb8ad4-b1be-4017-a753-4cac31adf423" />
        <Place Id="fb03dc89-12a0-49cd-b978-a7e4bc355bdb" />
        <Place Id="35700ff7-6405-4ca8-9e74-a44da2e0d1c0" />
        <Place Id="f3be70c9-93a7-4824-b4b0-3d8d6bc317a5" />
        <Place Id="be980a4e-49ac-4b29-8e25-92937545e088" />
        <Place Id="612734a4-ead9-4fd2-9d14-d0a557464bec" />
        <Place Id="f753c89a-6e9a-4dbb-bf37-2110ab941293" />
        <Place Id="5d318aab-2775-4dd3-81b4-2f78f5d3bcbd" />
        <Place Id="2b6c033d-9be7-41c3-ad14-60a59ef490b0" />
        <Place Id="3aea20d0-ec44-48b4-8456-0d923499c299" />
        <Place Id="a57db94e-8bb7-4818-af19-9a7acbcf5e37" />
        <Place Id="85b49eb4-2674-4b39-98c3-fc99c74293a0" />
        <Place Id="1fbb02b0-3cc9-48ea-8f29-63c558424bb9" />
        <Place Id="9ed0fd93-9482-40a1-840a-9f3f880bbb0b" />
        <Place Id="fc41d588-e495-4c4d-91cd-88949f367264" />
        <Place Id="4d401101-207b-4a37-a9fe-957d147712b4" />
        <Place Id="fd961ab9-886e-47d6-9be6-8acb47a2765b" />
        <Place Id="f06b4ceb-7872-4f1c-87f9-5a1bfb428958" />
        <Place Id="a71189db-2198-4c34-b57f-8de5a5938cbf" />
        <Place Id="12d9bfe8-6929-49bf-a78d-d17cf7685c9b" />
        <Place Id="d675a530-5e9e-4cf4-990a-566386e5fb8a" />
        <Place Id="496b00bf-2e21-4f34-a11a-06235769e84c" />
        <Place Id="0bf88c52-6c56-481c-943e-1c174de79d25" />
        <Place Id="15dafb9c-f90a-476f-a6ad-cde5db74407c" />
        <Place Id="a21c3a36-5c6d-42e6-99e6-b1992ec7a37e" />
        <Place Id="5bb4e85f-99f8-4ab2-82e8-d6ae10a316bd" />
        <Place Id="24dc5ffa-c785-4b73-8bc0-1bd43ae591d0" />
        <Place Id="372c67b7-59aa-42a4-9638-ff4e5282d0eb" />
        <Place Id="27f9e128-86df-4280-87e8-9355c1061ce4" />
        <Place Id="3f409342-70a1-4d2d-b933-bf8726c9be21" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
    <Group Id="f3329004-7163-46e8-9888-3ecd1551e4c6" BlockedSalesChannelID="fc483f27-ba50-4441-a609-65cadb6d6564">
      <Places>
        <Place Id="7b116ee5-8f1f-42b8-9eaa-2be6b29ce8d6" />
        <Place Id="c90c7156-9b5f-44eb-8e59-672b4f47c248" />
        <Place Id="0f5995ce-47ac-453d-b37c-a04d1dcbd211" />
        <Place Id="ac1200b6-ee15-4c16-9c33-4413c9577b6c" />
        <Place Id="56905ff8-369d-4f6e-8e77-0f5e2f780796" />
        <Place Id="e6fb8ad4-b1be-4017-a753-4cac31adf423" />
        <Place Id="fb03dc89-12a0-49cd-b978-a7e4bc355bdb" />
        <Place Id="35700ff7-6405-4ca8-9e74-a44da2e0d1c0" />
        <Place Id="f3be70c9-93a7-4824-b4b0-3d8d6bc317a5" />
        <Place Id="be980a4e-49ac-4b29-8e25-92937545e088" />
        <Place Id="612734a4-ead9-4fd2-9d14-d0a557464bec" />
        <Place Id="f753c89a-6e9a-4dbb-bf37-2110ab941293" />
        <Place Id="5d318aab-2775-4dd3-81b4-2f78f5d3bcbd" />
        <Place Id="2b6c033d-9be7-41c3-ad14-60a59ef490b0" />
        <Place Id="3aea20d0-ec44-48b4-8456-0d923499c299" />
        <Place Id="a57db94e-8bb7-4818-af19-9a7acbcf5e37" />
        <Place Id="85b49eb4-2674-4b39-98c3-fc99c74293a0" />
        <Place Id="1fbb02b0-3cc9-48ea-8f29-63c558424bb9" />
        <Place Id="9ed0fd93-9482-40a1-840a-9f3f880bbb0b" />
        <Place Id="fc41d588-e495-4c4d-91cd-88949f367264" />
        <Place Id="4d401101-207b-4a37-a9fe-957d147712b4" />
        <Place Id="fd961ab9-886e-47d6-9be6-8acb47a2765b" />
        <Place Id="f06b4ceb-7872-4f1c-87f9-5a1bfb428958" />
        <Place Id="a71189db-2198-4c34-b57f-8de5a5938cbf" />
        <Place Id="12d9bfe8-6929-49bf-a78d-d17cf7685c9b" />
        <Place Id="d675a530-5e9e-4cf4-990a-566386e5fb8a" />
        <Place Id="496b00bf-2e21-4f34-a11a-06235769e84c" />
        <Place Id="0bf88c52-6c56-481c-943e-1c174de79d25" />
        <Place Id="15dafb9c-f90a-476f-a6ad-cde5db74407c" />
        <Place Id="a21c3a36-5c6d-42e6-99e6-b1992ec7a37e" />
        <Place Id="5bb4e85f-99f8-4ab2-82e8-d6ae10a316bd" />
        <Place Id="24dc5ffa-c785-4b73-8bc0-1bd43ae591d0" />
        <Place Id="372c67b7-59aa-42a4-9638-ff4e5282d0eb" />
        <Place Id="27f9e128-86df-4280-87e8-9355c1061ce4" />
        <Place Id="3f409342-70a1-4d2d-b933-bf8726c9be21" />
      </Places>
    </Group>
  </SalesChannelGroups>
</IGPosEvtHallStruct>
```

There are approximately 500 rows in the table. The XML column data is of similar format. The only valuable data exists are in the CustomGroup Section (it can be 1 or 2 sections. Nevertheless all of those are needed). Can someone help me to convert the output of this table and XML into a new table with the below columns:

```
ID (from above table)
DS_RowGuid
PCScreenStructureVariantID
GroupID
GroupSeatsID
PlaceId
```

Much appreciated.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Not sure you got the *minimal* bit of [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```sql
SELECT
  t.ID,
  t.DS_RowGuid,
  t.PCScreenStructureVariantID,
  GroupID      = x1.Groups.value('@Id'          ,'uniqueidentifier'),
  GroupSeatsID = x1.Groups.value('@GroupSeatsId','uniqueidentifier'),
  PlaceId      = x2.Places.value('@Id'          ,'uniqueidentifier')
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY t.XML.nodes('IGPosEvtHallStruct/CustomGroups/Group') x1(Groups)
CROSS APPLY x1.Groups.nodes('Places/Place') x2(Places);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=388f86e846ff66f1ca7a0cf2cc67ef6d)

- Note how the first `.nodes` breaks out the `Group` nodes, and is then fed into the second one to break out the `Place` nodes. This is only necessary because we are selecting from two different levels of the XML
- When using `.value` the XQuery must be known to be exactly one node. This is only true with attributes (referred by `@`), but if you wanted a node's inner text value, you would need `'.value('(someNode/text())[1]',` etc

Comment: You are a life saver. The output was exactly as I was looking for. You just solved a real-life problem for me with this Charlie. Thanks.

I was not aware of the minimal reproducible example requirement. Thanks for pointing that out and will hereon ensure complying to it (where possible) before posting any other questions I may have.